# Python workflow returns ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indexer' when it once worked fine

Tags: python, docker, modulenotfounderror, indexer, pyspellchecker

I have a Python workflow that reads local folders, uploads pix to google cloud for processing, and returns json files back to other local folders. This workflow worked fine.

I used this script:

```
#!/bin/bash   
    
    # Create and activate a Python virtual environment
    python -m venv dg_ocr_env
    source dg_ocr_env/bin/activate
    
    # Deactivate any existing Conda environment
    conda deactivate
    
    # Upgrade pip
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    
    # Install packages from requirements.txt
    pip install -r /Users/XXXX/Desktop/ocv/00_setup_VENV_dg_ocr/requirements.txt
```

...and I was then able to run my main.py script without error.

Then, I tried dockerizing and hit this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indexer'
```

I thought this might've had something to do with Docker only…whether individual build or docker compose, rebuilding with no cache (and every other way I have found scouring the Internet), I got the following error or something like it:

```
docker run ocr-image              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/unified_ocr_2_json.py", line 15, in <module>
    from spellchecker import SpellChecker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spellchecker/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from  spellchecker.core import Spellchecker,getInstance
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spellchecker/core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from indexer import DictionaryIndex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indexer'
```

what I tried:
In trying to get some clarity on the process, I wiped another computer, set up a clean Monterey operating system, and installed nothing in it except for Anaconda, Brew, and sublime.txt.

I then tried to recreate from my directory of py scripts, etc., i,e., the workflow that had a very short time ago worked just fine locally:

I ran my .sh (shown above):
…and now here is the most recent traceback from the clean computer:

```
python /Users/aiki/Desktop/ocv/unified_ocr_2_json.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aiki/Desktop/ocv/unified_ocr_2_json.py", line 11, in <module>
    from spellchecker import SpellChecker
  File "/Users/aiki/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spellchecker/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from  spellchecker.core import Spellchecker,getInstance
  File "/Users/aiki/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spellchecker/core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from indexer import DictionaryIndex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indexer'
```

My script.py calls:

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
```

Here is pip show spellchecker:

```
(dg_ocr_env) aware@awares-MacBook-Pro spellchecker % ls
__init__.py core.py     indexer.py  langdetect.py   resources   templates
__pycache__ dicts       info.py     py.typed    spellchecker.py utils.py
(dg_ocr_env) aware@awares-MacBook-Pro spellchecker %
```

and nano core.py:

```
#
import os
import string
import codecs
import inexactsearch
import urllib

from indexer import DictionaryIndex
from langdetect import _detect_lang

__all__ = ['Spellchecker', 'getInstance']
```

I have looked inside core.py (indexer is there...),
I have checked dependency conflicts,
I have checked requirements.txt and what spellchecker says it requires is listed,
And so so much more -

I have no idea what changed, all I know is: what used to work on one computer locally, now no longer works on either computer locally, let alone in any kind of docker container.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you install the module **inside the docker container**?

Comment: Can you show us your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! So: though I indeed am having issues with docker, it seems that taking docker out of it via my clean install leaves me thinking that it is not docker at all, but something else...I left the docker part in because it was part of my troubleshooting.

Comment: Others with similar errors have reported that their problem was because they installed the `spellchecker` module, when they should have installed `pyspellchecker` instead.  Try installing `pyspellchecker`.

Comment: @JohnGordon- Thank you sir - I did find that info very early on thanks. My initial requirements.txt pip freeze, back when it first worked, has BOTH those dependencies. And my original .py script called (as above)

from spellchecker import SpellChecker

and all worked.

Should you have any thoughts on removing spellchecker, using pyspellchecker and changing the import code in the .py. I am all ears (and very grateful).

Comment: PS- I just tried to follow up on your good idea in a more thorough way: removed spellchecker, used pyspellchecker, changed import in .py to use pyspellchecker and re-ran, and got

- "no module named 'pyspellchecker'

seems my .py can't find pyspellchecker either (or anything?) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer — John's comment above made me go down this particular road again…the key points found being this:

You would think that a pyspellchecker module would have required an import statement that would read something like this:

```
from pyspellchecker import SpellChecker
```

But it doesn't. Instead, the correct version is:

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
```

But that doesn't match the name of the module, does it? And further, there (really was) another module called spellchecker. Once I uninstalled both and reinstalled only pyspellchecker into my conda venv, things worked again.

But here are the things that led to that final discovery, as hopefully useful to someone else in troubleshooting this type of error:

1 — I started by printing the list of packages where I thought they might be to check for conflicts:

```
conda list
pip list
```

This didn't really help, so I discovered that I could:

2 — Verify the correct Python executable: In my .py script, I added print(sys.executable) to print the location of the Python executable. It (should) point to the Python executable inside my myenv environment.

3 — Then I learned that I could troubleshoot better by directly by running a python session in terminal. But first, to be clean about it:

```
Deactivate the current environment:
conda deactivate

Reactivate myenv environment:     
conda activate myenv
```

4 — Started a new Python interactive session by typing python and hitting enter.

```
python 
>>>

I checked:     

>>>import sys
>>>print(sys.executable)
>>>print(sys.version)
```

The Python interpreter path (from sys.executable) should point to the Python interpreter inside myenv environment, and the Python version (from sys.version) should be the one I expected for this environment.

5 — Once I knew the path, and still in the same python session direct in terminal:

```
>>>import site
>>>print(site.getsitepackages())
```

This prints the list of directories Python is using to look for site-packages (third-party libraries).

6 — Exit Python, exit() and list the contents of the site-packages directory for myenv environment:

```
ls /Users/XXXX/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

This listed all the packages installed in myenv. I checked if pyspellchecker was in this list. It was. And something else was also…

There was also a spellchecker directory listed there.

7 — So I tried to import using the spellchecker name. Run a python terminal session again and:

```
>>>import spellchecker
>>>print(spellchecker.__file__)
```

If the import succeeds, this prints the path to the module that was imported. I will be able to see if it corresponds to pyspellchecker or something else, but it failed, and that meant these were conflicting, right?

The module that Python is finding when I import spellchecker is different from pyspellchecker, which is why there's a conflict when I try to import pyspellchecker.

8 — So maybe the best course of action is to uninstall both packages and then reinstall only pyspellchecker.

9 — Remember to exit the Python interpreter when you're done testing by typing exit() or hitting Ctrl+D. And then:

```
pip uninstall pyspellchecker spellchecker
pip install pyspellchecker
```

After (all) this, everything works.

Thanks to all who helped me down this road!